# Can anyone explain to me what happened to my flash drive?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, usb-flash-drive

I went to a library, copied some files from their computer (using Windows XP) to my flash drive (formatted to FAT16) and disconnected the drive using safely remove option.

When I accessed the drive on my computer, I found that the only thing that it seems to have is a shortcut called `My Removable Device.lnk` leading to `C:\Windows\system32\rundll32.exe ~$WCPXVE.docx,_fndot@16 desktop.ini " "`

When I open the shortcut (on my computer running Windows 7), I can see all the files I stored on the drive, all the filed I previously had on the drive, and I can copy files off the drive with no problems at all.

Windows reports used disk space correctly on the flash drive.

So I'm trying to figure out how they did that and that benefits such procedure gives to the library.

Comment: 'When I accessed the drive on my computer', 'When I open it (on my computer running Windows 7)' - where's the difference?

Comment: @Gotschi  I'm sorry, I meant when I use the shortcut.

Comment: If WCPXVE.doc is not something you know I would format the USB ASAP. Could be malware. I hope you have not run anything from the device.

Comment: It seems to be virus. The files might be converted to `System files`. If you want to see the file, change the visibility mode in file organizer of windows explorer.

Comment: O, you *have* run something. You may be hosed now. *NEVER* execute unknown stuff. I suggest you run good antivirus on your machine now.

Comment: Yeah, it's been so long since I used a public computer that I completely forgot about possibility of malware running on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be due to a virus/malware

see here for more info: http://en.kioskea.net/faq/8734-files-on-flash-drive-changed-to-shortcuts

Comment: Looks like this was it. I just wasn't paranoid enough with the flash drive.